# How to add common header in Rails with Grape?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, design-patterns, ruby-grape

Is there any way that I can common header in Rails with Grape so I do not have to specify the same header over and over again?

```
namespace :user do
  desc 'Return a user.', {
    headers: {
      "Authorization" => {
        description: "Some Token",
        required: true
      }
    }
  }
  get do
    {}
  end
end
```

Notice that headers would have to be specified over and over in all my APIs since I want them to be secure. Is there a shortcut way (a design pattern) that I can follow without creating this header everytime?

And no I am not looking for something like this:

```
def headers
  {
    "Authorization" => {
      description: "Some Token",
      required: true
    }
  }
end

namespace :user do
  desc 'Return a user.', {
    headers: headers
  }
  get do
    {}
  end
end
```

Comment: Why is the `def headers` example not good? You're discounting this option too quickly. You can always make the method take arguments and merge them into the result hash.

Comment: A design pattern you could use is inheritance.Create a base class that always implements the Authorization header and extend from that.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I did:

app/api/api.rb

```
def my_headers
  {
    key1: {
      description: 'hello',
      required: true
    },
    key2: {
      description: 'hello',
      required: false
    }
  }
end

# define my_headers outside of API class

class API < Grape::API
  version 'v1', using: :param, parameter: 'v', vendor: 'Larvata'
  content_type :json, 'application/json'

  # some codes ...
```

app/api/home.rb

```
class Home < API

 resources :home do

    desc "Home Page", { headers: my_headers }
    get do
      # some codes ...
```

---

oh, sorry, you are looking for this solution ...

Comment: Move `def my_headers` below to  `resource :home` works too,   may be better?

Comment: But you have to define it in every resource.

Answer (score 2):

This worked well.
You can add class method that returns header definitions to api root class and call it from each api class.

app/api/root.rb

```
module Api
  class Root < Grape::API
    def self.headers_definition
      {
        "Authorization" => {
          description: "Some Token",
          required: true
        }
      }
    end

    mount Home
  end
end
```

app/api/home.rb

```
module Api
  class Home < Grape::API
    resources :home do

      desc "Home Page", headers: Root.headers_definition
        get do
         # some codes ...
        end
      end  
    end
  end
end
```